# error in connecting access database in c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

i am getting error "security issue : the connection string may contain a password"

i want to connect access database with my c++ program using ODBC.
i am using visual studio 2008.

following are the steps what i have done to create this
created simple access database (testdb.mdb) and added user dsn(test)
then created mfc application in database support i selected database view with file support and selected odbc and cliked button data source and selected my created dsn(test)

now when i build this that above error occurs what shoul i do ?

Answer (score 1):

just remove the line

```
#error Security Issue: The connection string may contain a password
```

from the generated header file.

it is there just to make you aware of that it is not good to have hardcoded passwords in your code.